# F# Function Matching

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching

Is there a way in F# to define a function that gives the sum of all the natural numbers up to the integer parameter provided, without using a `match` construct.

In other words, why is the following code wrong?

```
let Sum 0 = 0
let Sum n = n + Sum (n - 1)
```

Comment: Not really, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm just asking out of curiosity, and because Haskell supports that kind of syntax and I find it somewhat elegant.

Comment: In that case not really but it might be possible with some terrible hackery though if you are desperate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specifically want the recursive form without using `match`, just use a regular conditional:

```
let rec Sum n = 
  if n = 0 then 0 else n + Sum (n-1)
```

The idiomatic way to emulate Haskell would be:

```
let rec Sum = function
| 0 -> 0
| n -> n + Sum (n-1)
```

But you actually don't need recursion since there is a closed form; see the "too obvious" part of @bytebuster's code.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is wrong because it contains a double definition of `Sum`. F# syntax is different to Haskell's and it requires a single function entry with branching done inside, using `match` or a chain of `if`'s.

Also, such code is not very accurate because it falls into an infinite loop if received a negative argument.

There are several simple ways to do what you need without `match`. Note, they also require argument range check:

```
let Sum1 x = x * (x+1) / 2   // too obvious
let Sum2 x = Seq.init id |> Seq.take (x+1) |> Seq.sum
```

Comment: I was just wondering why the following statement is considered valid `let Sum 0 = 0`, but neither documentation, nor books point that something can be done with this construct.

Comment: It wouldn't actually be an infinite loop.  When x is equal to Int32.MinValue, subtracting one from it will yield Int32.MaxValue, and eventually the value would reach zero.